# Install PyTorch 1.3 via Anaconda

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

My current PyTorch version is 1.10. I want to downgrade it to 1.3 but conda suggests the CPU-only version. My GPU is a GTX 1080 TI.

My current setup is

```sh
cudatoolkit               10.2.89         hfd86e86_1  
cudnn                     7.6.5           cuda10.2_0  
pytorch                   1.10.0          py3.7_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0             cuda    pytorch
```

When I execute:

```
conda install pytorch==1.3.0 torchvision -c pytorchCollecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/lorenzp/.conda/envs/detection

  added / updated specs:
    - pytorch==1.3.0
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cpuonly-1.0                |                0           2 KB  pytorch
    pytorch-1.3.0              |      py3.7_cpu_0        36.1 MB  pytorch
    torchvision-0.4.1          |         py37_cpu        14.6 MB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        50.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cpuonly            pytorch/noarch::cpuonly-1.0-0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  pytorch                1.10.0-py3.7_cuda10.2_cudnn7.6.5_0 --> 1.3.0-py3.7_cpu_0
  torchvision                             0.11.1-py37_cu102 --> 0.4.1-py37_cpu


Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.
```

It just suggests the CPU-only version. How to find the GPU version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I needed to find the right cudatoolkit. For that

```sh
conda search cudatoolkit
```

Then, I installed I can choose version somewhere between Cuda 9.2 and 10.0. I
took a look at https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions and made a guess of the cuda version.

In my case:

```sh
conda install cudatoolkit==10.0.130
```

This automatically installed `PyTorch==1.3.1`.